# Can we interact with browser while ajax is being processed?

Tags: ajax, browser

When a browser sends an ajax request, and the response we are getting is taking some time.. so in the meantime can my users interact with browser or ajax is only for not refreshing the whole page but the users have to wait for the response to come?

Answer (score 0):

No the user may not wait for the responce if you wish, however you if the future user interaction depends on the results of the ajax request. For instance entering a postcode may make an ajax call to load suburbs associated with that postcode and the user may need to use that suburb for instance if this page is a signup page etc in which case it is recommended to disallow user to make further interactions

More info on here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29

Tutorials here
http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp